# SSRS Parameters IIF Expression

Tags: reporting-services

I have two parameters 1 is called `DataAreaId` and is set to a value by the database behind the scenes (Dynamics AX). I have another parameter which is multi select called `Company`. Now I am trying to pass the parameter value from `DataAreaId` to `Company` based on a condition.

If the `DataAreaId = "002"` then the default value for the `Company` parameter must be select all, if not then the company parameter must equal the `DataAreaId` parameter. I have tried this and other permutations but I am having no joy. I appreciate any support you can offer me.

```
=iif(Parameters!dataareaid.Value = "002", join(Parameters!company.Value,","),Parameters!dataareaid.Value)
```

Comment: how are the available values for the company parameter set?

Comment: are you sure the dataareaid is DataAreaId = "002" and not DataAreaId = 002?

Answer (score 2):

Do this in a dataset.

```
if @DataAreaId = '002'
    select xxx from yyy
    --Same query here as you use to populate Company
else
    select xxx from yyy where zzz = @DataAreaId
    --Same query here as you use to populate Company
    --but add a WHERE clause that only gives
    --the row matching DataAreaId
```

Use this dataset as the source of "default values" for the Company parameter.